# Unable to installing bitcoinjs-server on Mac OSX 10.9.1

Tags: c++, macos, node.js, bitcoin

I'm following instructions provided on github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-server

The following dependencies were installed

**OpenSSL**

```
christianmacedo:bitcoinjs-server$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

**pkg-config:**
Can't figure out how to get this. Although is *seems* to be installed.

**Node.js**

```
christianmacedo:bitcoinjs-server$ node -v
v0.10.25
```

When attempting to install bitcoinjs with npm...

```
    christianmacedo:~$ sudo npm install bitcoinjs -g
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bitcoinjs
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bitcoinjs
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/step
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/irc
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonrpc2
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yanop
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/progress-bar
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/leveldb
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/binary
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/step
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/irc
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignum
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonrpc2
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yanop
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/progress-bar
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffertools
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/leveldb
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary
    npm WARN engine leveldb@0.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.6.13  buffertools@2.0.1 install /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/buffertools
    > node-gyp rebuild

      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/buffertools/buffertools.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/buffertools.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/buffertools.node: Finished
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/put
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cliff/0.1.8
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/flatiron
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nconf
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-monitor/1.2.3
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nssocket
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/put
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/flatiron
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cliff/0.1.8
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nconf
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nssocket
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-monitor/1.2.3
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway/0.2.9
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.6.0
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/director/1.1.10
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ps-tree
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/director/1.1.10
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.6.0
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.11
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway/0.2.9
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ps-tree
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/event-stream
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ini
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-jar
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/event-stream
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2/0.4.12
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.9
    npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ini
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2/0.4.12
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/0.2.1
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/0.2.1
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
    npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
    npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
    npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})
    npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.24"})

    > bignum@0.6.2 install /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/bignum
    > node-gyp configure build

      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bignum/bignum.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bignum.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bignum.node: Finished

    > kerberos@0.0.3 install /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
      CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node: Finished

    > bson@0.2.5 install /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node: Finished

    > leveldb@0.7.1 preinstall /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/leveldb
    > make build

    if [ ! -d ./build ]; then node-gyp configure; fi
    node-gyp build
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/builder.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/db_impl.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/db_iter.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/filename.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/dbformat.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/log_reader.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/log_writer.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/memtable.o
    ../deps/leveldb/db/memtable.cc:104:31: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'const size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      assert((p + val_size) - buf == encoded_len);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
        (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                            ^
    1 warning generated.
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/repair.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/table_cache.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/version_edit.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/version_set.o
    ../deps/leveldb/db/version_set.cc:58:13: warning: unused function 'IntSetToString' [-Wunused-function]
    std::string IntSetToString(const std::set& s) {
                ^
    1 warning generated.
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/db/write_batch.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/port/port_posix.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/block.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/filter_block.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/block_builder.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/format.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/iterator.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/merger.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/table.o
    ../deps/leveldb/table/table.cc:231:13: warning: unused variable 'handle' [-Wunused-variable]
          Slice handle = iiter->value();
                ^
    1 warning generated.
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/table_builder.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/table/two_level_iterator.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/arena.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/bloom.o
    ../deps/leveldb/util/bloom.cc:50:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
        for (size_t i = 0; i key();
                  ^
    ../deps/leveldb/util/cache.cc:163:12: warning: private field 'last_id_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
      uint64_t last_id_;
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/coding.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/comparator.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/crc32c.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/env.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/env_posix.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/filter_policy.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/hash.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/logging.o
    ../deps/leveldb/util/logging.cc:67:40: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'const int' and 'unsigned long long' [-Wsign-compare]
              (v == kMaxUint64/10 && delta > kMaxUint64%10)) {
                                     ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/options.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/leveldb/deps/leveldb/util/status.o
      LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/leveldb.a
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-sinksource.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy-stubs-internal.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/snappy/deps/snappy/snappy.o
    ../deps/snappy/snappy.cc:1012:20: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
        if (op - base_ , AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:234:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:294:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:340:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:400:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:468:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:536:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:144:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:591:46: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpenAsync::Hook' requested here
      NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "open", OpenAsync::Hook);
                                                 ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:144:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:592:49: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpenAsync::Hook' requested here
      NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "destroy", OpenAsync::Hook);
                                                    ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:77:12: error: no matching function for call to 'AsyncQueue'
        return AsyncQueue(op, AsyncWorker, AsyncCallback);
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:144:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpAsync::AsyncEnqueue' requested here
        return AsyncEnqueue(op);
               ^
    ../src/cpp/handle.cc:593:48: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'node_leveldb::JHandle::OpenAsync::Hook' requested here
      NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "repair", OpenAsync::Hook);
                                                   ^
    ../src/cpp/helpers.h:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'AsyncCallback' matching 'const uv_after_work_cb' (aka 'void (*const)(uv_work_t *, int)') for 3rd argument
    static inline Handle AsyncQueue(
                                ^
    9 errors generated.
    make[1]: *** [Release/obj.target/leveldb/src/cpp/handle.o] Error 1
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
    gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build"
    gyp ERR! cwd /opt/local/lib/node_modules/bitcoinjs/node_modules/leveldb
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    make: *** [build] Error 1
    npm ERR! leveldb@0.7.1 preinstall: `make build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the leveldb@0.7.1 preinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the leveldb package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     make build
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls leveldb
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bitcoinjs" "-g"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/christianmacedo
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/christianmacedo/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

And to fix this I've tried a couple of things which have been recommended, but the error remains.

- Deleting ~/tmp contents
- [Installing python, make and C++](https://github.com/rvagg/node-leveldown/issues/69)

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like leveldb is failing to install. Try installing it via homebrew ?

Comment: @Bulkan,tried installing leveldb but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using

```
sudo npm install bitcoinjs -g
```

use:

```
sudo apt install bitcoinjs -g
```